# Help with android layout?

Tags: android

I have TableLayout and i have ads on my app, but the ads go up under the last button on the screen, 
how can i get the ad to stick to the bottom of the screen?

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textView1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/time" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<Button 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_centerInParent="true"   
android:id="@+id/totime" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Save" 
android:id="@+id/save" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>

<com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView
```

android:id="@+id/mobFoxView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
publisherId="**********************"
/>

Comment: i added some code its TableLayout layout

Answer (score 1):

Then, use `RelativeLayout`, and put something like:

```
<com.mobfox.sdk.MobFoxView
    android:id="@+id/mobFoxView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    publisherId="**********" />
```

You will have to modify your widgets above the `MobFoxView`... maybe you can leave them inside the `TableLayout`, and put that TableLayout inside the `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TableLayout>
        your other Stuff
    </TableLayout>
    <MobFoxStuff/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i get xml unbound prefix on textview?

Comment: you must be missing to your main relative layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"